# Cannot login after setting up stagging website for WP

Tags: wordpress, staging

I have a live site (example.com). Instead of making changes and finding bugs when the public can view the site, I decided to setup a staging webiste. I followed the directions for setting it up [here](https://themeisle.com/blog/wordpress-staging-site/).

It appears to have worked, when I go to staging.example.com everything is there. But when I try to login staging.example.com/wp-admin.php it keeps giving

> ERROR: Invalid username. Lost your password?

I tried my normal password and the password I used to create the new database.

What did I do wrong or what step did I miss? How can I add a new user to the staging account? I checked wp-config.php and believe I have the `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER` and `DB_PASSWORD` correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is browser caching and cookies.
Try to open the page in anonymous window or another browser, or fully clear your cache and cookies

> staging.example.com/wp-admin.php

This path does not exist, you need go to

> staging.example.com/wp-admin/

When you need to create new user with database - you can open the database with phpMyadmin, and create user in the table wp_users. The password field must be left blank, and then go to the wp-login.php and recover the password to setup new one.